# Add attachment annotation in pdf and executed within web application jar

Tags: annotations, itext, attachment

I am implementing adding attachment annotation in pdf using itext annotation, but very funny is that, duing to web application framework restriction, i must put the implementation codes and attachment file within jar file. Here is a brief hierarchy of the implementation:

1. package example.pdf

   - Implementation.java
   - attachment.doc

Main codes:

```
protected void createAttachment(PdfWriter writer, Rectangle rect, String 
templatePath, String fileName) throws IOException, DocumentException {
// Get instruction document
String embed = 
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(templatePath).getFile();

// The fileName here is used to display in the attachment list of the 
// document
PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
            writer, embed, fileName, null);

// The fileName here is used to display on the document
PdfAnnotation attachment =
            PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer, rect, fileName, fs);

// Specify the width and height of the icon area
PdfAppearance app = writer.getDirectContent().createAppearance(200, 200);
String wordIcon = 
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(WORD_ICON).getFile();
    Image img = Image.getInstance(wordIcon);
    img.scaleAbsolute(200, 200);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

    app.addImage(img);
    attachment.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, app);
    writer.addAnnotation(attachment);
}
```

The above codes will be called by the service class:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(220, 620, 250, 640);
    createAttachment(pdfWriter, rect, "pdf/attachment.doc", 
"attachment.doc");
```

It works normally under my IDE, but once i made them as a jar(including the attachment), it appears the attachment could not be found/attached by the web application. And told me that the file could not be located in system path.

I know it might be the issue that relates to class path detect mechanism(for example class loader and loading method), but it really blocked me to move further since i did not find any possible solution.

The exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\work\test-1.3.6.0- 
SNAPSHOT.jar!\pdf\attachment.doc (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(Unknown Source)
at example.pdf.Implementation.createAttachment
```

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The only difference is take the input stream instead of filename, the class PdfFileSpecification has such interface for doing so.

```
        InputStream embedInputStream = 
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(templatePath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        embedOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len = -1;
        while ((len = embedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            embedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // The fileName here is used to display in the attachment list of the document
        PdfFileSpecification fs = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
                writer, null, fileName, embedOutputStream.toByteArray());

        // The fileName here is used to display on the document
        PdfAnnotation attachment =
                PdfAnnotation.createFileAttachment(writer, rect, fileName, fs);
```